# Adjoint of reduce sum operation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Consider the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ defined as follows
$$
f(X) = X 1_{m\times 1}
$$
This is essentially a reduce operation that collapses the rows of $X$ into their sum. What is the adjoint of this operation?

## Attempted Solution

$$
\begin{align}
    \langle X1, y\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n} 
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\sum_{j=1}^m x_{ij} \\
    &= \sum_i \sum_j y_i x_{ij} \\
    &= \text{trace}\left(X^\top y 1_{n\times 1}^\top\right) \\
    &= \langle X, y1_{n\times 1}^\top \rangle_F \\
    &= \text{vec}(X)^\top \text{vec}(y1_{n\times 1}) \\
    &= \langle \text{vec}(X), \text{vec}(y1_{n\times 1}^\top) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^2}
\end{align}
$$
still no clue..

Comment: You got the solution on the 4th line: $y\mapsto y1_{1\times n}$. Btw the subscripts $F$ and later $\Bbb R^2$ both should rather be $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$.

Comment: @Berci I thought that could be it, but usually when people talk about adjoints they look for $\langle AX, Y\rangle = \langle X, A^* Y\rangle$ where $A^*$ multiplies $Y$ from the left, not the right

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, since $y\mapsto y1_{1\times n}$ is a *linear* map, it will also have a matrix ($A\in\Bbb R^{n\times(nm)}$) that gives $Ay=({\rm vec})(y1_{1\times n}$.

Comment: Btw exactly the same applies to $f$ itself. The point is that we (implicitly) vectorize the matrices. Can you find the matrix of $f$? Then just take the transpose.

Comment: @Berci I am very lost do you mind summarising this information?

Comment: How is $Ay$ defined if $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$?

Comment: Calculate $f(X)$ for the $X$ in the standard basis of (vectorized) $n\times m$ matrices.

Comment: You mean the basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_{nm}\}$ where each $e_i = \text{vec}(E_i)$?

Comment: In that case I guess $f(X) = a_1 e_1 + \ldots + a_{nm} e_{nm}$ and we shold have $a_i = x_{i1} + \ldots + x_{im}$.

Comment: Wait no each $e_i$ is $nm$ dimensional but $X1$ is only $n$ dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly obtained the adjoint in the 4th line of your argument:

$$\langle X\,1_{m\times 1},\,y\rangle_{\Bbb R^n}\ =\ \langle X,\,y\,1_{1\times m}\rangle_{\Bbb R^{n\times m}}$$
so the adjoint of the linear map $f(X)=X\,1_{m\times 1}$ is the linear map $f^*(y)=y\,1_{1\times m}$.

Note that the definitions of both these maps involve multiplying by a fixed matrix from the right, however, if we vectorize $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$, just as for any linear map, we can write them in the form
$$f(x)=Ax\quad f^*(y)=By$$
for some matrices $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times nm}$ and $B\in\Bbb R^{nm\times n}$, and we'll also have $B=A^\top$.

Comment: Makes sense! I get very confused with the fact that things keep on getting vectorized and then devectorized and I am not sure why we need those operations if they are isomorphic spaces.

Comment: We don't actually need to vectorize anything here! It was just about your confusion that you wanted to see the linear map acting as multiplying by a matrix on the left.